# Consulta JavaScript - CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, html, c#, jquery

una consulta , tengo un botón en asp.net que realiza unos procesos en el Server side

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="button1"  runat="server" Text="INGRESAR" OnClick="Button1_Click" ></asp:Button>
```

Pero tras esto tengo que generar un **popup** ( Alerta ) simplemente como aviso, ahora, yo he estado generando este **popup** con el siguiente código desde el **CodeBehind** tras algunas ciertas validaciones y etc

```
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Texto Alert');", true);
```

*Cabe recalcar que con el script de arriba ejecuta la sentencia, o sea no uso un < script/> o un href a algun archivo JS*

Por lo que tengo entendido y he visto en la mayoría de ejemplos es que todos los que trabajan los popups lo hacen en el ClientSide(de JS) y tras un clic en un botón usando el **OnClientClick** pero mi consulta es , como puedo realizar que una función de javascript se ejecute tras el término o condición de mi codebehind.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, muchas gracias.